# Battery draining on Ubuntu touch on BQ M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, battery, m10

After playing a youtube video for 90 minutes the battery is 50% drained.
Has anybody else watched this on his BQ M10?

I am asking because i want to now, if that is a bug or a hardware problem on my tablet.

Comment: Ussually doesn't drain that fast for me but I'm ussually autoplaying youtube in the background on convergence mode so may not be a like for like comparision.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an email to support center of bq for that problem.

**They gave me some tips how to calibrate the battery in case that the battery  has to less power:**

1. When the battery is completely empty, load the battery for 8 hours.
2. Repeat this 3 times.